# Copy iOS video quality settings for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, videoquality

When you setup UIImagePickerController one can/should setup the video quality, like:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeHigh // Setting video quality
imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
```

The thing is that iOS has its own video quality setup, when you go to Settings > Camera > Record Video. Is there a way to set the imagePicker quality to match the iOS setup?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to map the same setting for the `UIImagePickerController`, there is only one way to control video quality that you already mentioned:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/qualitytype